# Express server stops without throwing error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, sequelize.js, yeoman-generator-angular

I am using the angular fullstack generator, but I do not believe this is the problem. I am working with Stripe.js and trying to save the data to the SQLite database using Sequelize. I have tried many different things, but the server stops running when it gets to the part where it is supposed to save the data.

```js
  app.post('/register', auth.isAuthenticated(), function(req,res){
    console.log('access: ',req.query)
    var userId = req.body._id
    var data = req.body.data
    //create stripe acct for artists
    stripe.accounts.create(data, function(err,acct){

      if(err){
        console.log('err!!! ', err)
      } else {
        console.log('acct: ', acct)
        //look for user in database
        db.User.find({
            where: {
              _id: userId
            }
          })
          .then(function(user) {
            if(user){
              console.log('user: ', user)
              //add stripe acct info to db
              console.log('acct:', user.dataValues.account);
            /*this is where the Server stops running*/
              user.updateAttributes({
                account: JSON.stringify(acct)
              }).success(function(){
                console.log('newacct:', user.dataValues.account);
                //just to see if it works
                res.send({'account': acct});

              })



            } else {
              console.log('no user found bruh')
            }
          });
        
      }

    })
  })
```

I have tried redirecting, changing req.method to 'get' and then res.redirect. res.end() all of the above, but it always stops running. No errors are thrown it just simply says 'Stopping Express Server'. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where it says it's stopping the express server

Comment: probably, there is a middleware code, that stops the express server when there is an unhanded exception. Can you edit that code to log the error and you could debug what went wrong

Comment: @KeithM What happens is it gets to the line user.updateAttributes and the server stops.

Comment: @prasun I see what you are saying! I will try that